# TempData[] getting wiped despite no requests taking place

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

TempData is supposed to persist for a subsequent request. However when I check the TempData in a subsequent controller I get a null. Why is TempData[] getting wiped off. Here are my two controllers. I am calling them in succession. So TempData[] should persist from one request to the next. Here is code from controller 1:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditCampaign(int? Id)
{

    ViewBag.Banner = bannerText.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
    // This is passed in case we need to add a new product or edit one. Then we'll
    // need the campaign id for reference purposes.
    TempData["campaign_id"] = Id;
    TempData["campaignBanner"] = bannerText.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
    ViewBag.StartDate = debugger.startDate.ToShortDateString();
    ViewBag.EndDate = debugger.endDate.ToShortDateString();
    int Id1 = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["campaign_id"]);
    int convertedId1 = Id1
```

Here is where I try to get the value in Controller 2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditCampaign(CampaignDTO camps)
{
    // Do this up top. i.e. get the campaign ID
    camps.Id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["campaign_id"]);
    string success = "";
```

I suspect that assigning the value of TempData in the penultimate line of controller 1 might be wiping off the data. If thats the case that is something new and not documented. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the data is enough to remove it. Here's the relevant source:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        object value;
        if (TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            _initialKeys.Remove(key);
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        _data[key] = value;
        _initialKeys.Add(key);
    }
}
```

So in controller 1, when you say:

```
int Id1 = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["campaign_id"]);
```

you are actually removing the data you just inserted.

There are many ways to work around this, but if you must read it from `TempData`, use `Peek()` instead.

Comment: Perfect answer. Never saw this before anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have some flawed info. The data stored in the TempData property persists for only one request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.tempdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: You mean to say it behaves exactly like ViewBag. I was thinking they are different.

Answer (score 1):

TempData is useful when you are redirecting (HTTP 302 or 303, i.e. RedirectToAction in MVC) to pass along some context.  It does not persist across separate HTTP requests. Based on your code sample, it suggests your client code first makes a GET to controller one, then issues a second request to controller two.

Your best bet is probably to return the necessary data as part of your response in controller one, then make that part of the incoming request to controller. You could potentially also use Session variables, https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98.

Comment: I also think in my case session variables are a better option then TempData[]. Thank You